# Shorter alternative for this jquery / javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

At a certain point in my webapp I have the following (large) series of loops:

```
jQuery.each(GO, function(index, item){  $("#GO_PUBS").append(
"<li><a href=javascript:dopage('"+item+"');>"+GO_desc[index]+"</a></li>");});

jQuery.each(AP, function(index, item){  $("#AP_PUBS").append(
"<li><a href=javascript:dopage('"+item+"');>"+AP_desc[index]+"</a></li>");});

jQuery.each(BV, function(index, item){  $("#BV_PUBS").append(
"<li><a href=javascript:dopage('"+item+"');>"+BV_desc[index]+"</a></li>");});

jQuery.each(FI, function(index, item){  $("#FI_PUBS").append(
"<li><a href=javascript:dopage('"+item+"');>"+FI_desc[index]+"</a></li>");});
```

The loop goes on and on but the pattern is always the same.

Is there any way I can make it way shorter by using some sort of array or list instead of explicitly writing it loop?

Thanks

Comment: that you have for each `XX` an `XX_desc` array too suggests that you should fix your internal data representation first.  Perhaps (for example) you need a 2D structure, not a whole load of separate 1D structures?

Comment: p.s. why use inline event handlers when you could have jQuery register the handlers, and make the page more efficient in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRY (Do not Repeat Yourself) : Start by creating a function to do that :

```
   function createLink(a,b,c){
        jQuery.each(a, function(index, item){  $(b).append(
        "<li><a href=javascript:dopage('"+item+"');>"+c[index]+"</a></li>");});
    }
```

And call

```
createLink(BV,"#BV_PUBS",BV_desc);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function xxx(a, b, c) {
    jQuery.each(a, function(index, item){
        $(b).append("<li><a href=javascript:dopage('"+item+"');>"+c[index]+"</a></li>");
    });
}

xxx(GO, "#GO_PUBS", GO_desc);
xxx(AP, "#AP_PUBS", AP_desc);
xxx(BV, "#BV_PUBS", BV_desc);
xxx(FI, "#FI_PUBS", FI_desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var iterator = function(id, array) {
  var $holder = $("#" + id);
  return function(index, item) {
    $holder.append("<li><a href=javascript:dopage('"+item+"');>"+array[index]+"</a></li>");
  };
};

jQuery.each(GO, iterator('GO_PUBS', GO_desc));
jQuery.each(AP, iterator('AP_PUBS', AP_desc));
jQuery.each(BV, iterator('BV_PUBS', BV_desc));
jQuery.each(FI, iterator('FI_PUBS', FI_desc));
```

---

If you are able to get hold of all the array(`GO, AP,..`) in a map like this:

```
var collection = {'GO': {asc: GO, desc: GO_desc}, ...};
```

You will be able to do something like this:

```
for(var key in collection) {
  if(collection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var arrMap = collection[key];
    jQuery.each(arrMap.asc, iterator(key + '_PUBS', arrMap.desc));
  }
}
```

---

### Update:

With 3D array:

```
var 3dArr = [['GO', GO, GO_desc], ...], 3dArrLen = 3dArr.length, i = 0;
for(i; i < 3dArrLen; i++) {
  var v = 3dArr[i];
  (function(id, arr, arr_desc) {
    jQuery.each(arr, iterator(id + '_PUBS', arr_desc));
  })(v[0], v[1], v[2]);
}
```

Comment: Note that in the comments to the question I suggested a 2D _array_, not an object, because using an object as a map as you have does not guarantee iteration order.

Comment: oh! I was not aware of OP's concerns about order. Let add that too! Thanks!

Comment: strictly speaking the OP hasn't expressed any concerns, but I think it's reasonable to assume that the elements need to be displayed in the order shown in the question.

Comment: hey, np... I too think thats good. The reason why i used `map` is OP needs the `id`. So, I used key for that. Now, since it is array, it has to be 3D to include the `id` key.